# Is it possible to use BLAS to speed up sparse matrix multiplication?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am currently trying to speed up my large sparse (scipy) matrix multiplications. I have successfully linked my numpy installation with OpenBLAS and henceforth, also scipy. I have run these [tests](https://gist.github.com/osdf/3842524#file_test_numpy.py) with success.

When I use `numpy.dot(X,Y)` I can clearly see performance boosts and also that multiple cores are used simultaneously. However, when I use scipy's dot functionality, no such performance boosts can be seen and still one one core is used. For example:

```
x = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(numpy.random.random((1000,1000)))
x.dot(x.T)
```

Does anyone know how I can make BLAS also work with scipy's dot functionality?

Comment: are you sure it is a matter of `.dot` functionality as opposed to `csr`?

Comment: well it's csr's own dot function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BLAS is just used for dense floating-point matrices. Matrix multiplication of a `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` is done using pure C++ functions that don't make any calls to external BLAS libraries.

For example, [matrix-matrix multiplication is implemented here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/84bc568aa6b86b2278b37b2d91d1f18d4adce67a/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr.h#L523), in `csr_matmat_pass_1` and `csr_matmat_pass_2`.

Optimised BLAS libraries are highly tuned to make efficient use of CPU caches by decomposing the dense input matrices into smaller block matrices in order to achieve better [locality-of-reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference). My understanding is that this strategy can't be easily applied to sparse matrices, where the non-zero elements may be arbitrarily distributed within the matrix.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. Do you know of any other way to speed up the matrix multiplication of sparse matrices? I also run into memory issues.

Comment: There might be, depending on your specific application. Do your matrices have some known sparsity structure, e.g. diagonal, banded, block? Does the output matrix have a known sparsity structure? I suggest you post another question, where you give as much information as you can about what your matrices are like, and what you plan on doing with the output.

Comment: Made a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25104733/how-to-efficiently-calculate-huge-matrix-multiplication-tfidf-features-in-pyth

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late to help you, but it may help someone else:

SciPy implementation of sparse matrix - sparse matrix multiplication is single-threaded only.

However, using https://pypi.org/project/sparse-dot-mkl/, your computation can run multithreaded, because the library uses intel MKL.