# Sparse matrix multipliaction numpy linked with mkl

Tags: numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, intel-mkl

I have numpy linked with mkl and I was doing matrix multiplication on sparse matrices and it seemed to be very slow. For example for matrix A of size (100000, 1000) , sparsity density = 0.1 and dtype=numpy.float64, I have
timeit A.T.dot(A) giving me 5.24s
but if I convert A to dense matrix and then do multiplication, I get ~650ms.
Does blas operation does not kick in for sparse matrices? Also I have observerd that my cpu usage shows only one core in use while doing sparse multiplication but uses multiple cores for dense case.

My numpy.show_config() has following configuration :

```
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/home/user/miniconda2/envs/sketch/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/home/user/miniconda2/envs/sketch/include']
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/home/user/miniconda2/envs/sketch/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/home/user/miniconda2/envs/sketch/include']
openblas_lapack_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/home/user/miniconda2/envs/sketch/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/home/user/miniconda2/envs/sketch/include']
blas_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/home/user/miniconda2/envs/sketch/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/home/user/miniconda2/envs/sketch/include']
```

Any thoughts on how I can make numpy's performance improve on sparse matrices. Thanks.

Comment: What's the dtype?

Comment: dtype is numpy.float64

Comment: If you have 41218703 nonzero values in a array with shape  (583250, 76), why are you using a sparse matrix?  Your array is 93% full!  Of course sparse matrix multiplication is slower than dense array multiplication with such a densely populated matrix.  Sparse matrices use a more complicated data structure than the simple block of memory used by dense arrays, and therefore require a multiplication algorithm written specifically for that data structure.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser You are right. But I think I have different issue because even with 10% nnz the sparse matrix multiplication seems to be like 10 times slower. Also my cpu usage shows only one core in use for sparse matrix mulitplication but uses multiple core for dense case. I have updated my question with information. Thanks

Comment: Also note that numpy knows nothing about sparse matrices.  They are implemented in scipy (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/tree/master/scipy/sparse).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Yeah. Also I have found this(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098653/is-it-possible-to-use-blas-to-speed-up-sparse-matrix-multiplication) which suggest that blas does not help with sparse matrices. Is there anything that can be done in this case then?  Thanks

Comment: From last year - https://stackoverflow.com/q/37536106/901925