# Directly use Intel mkl library on Scipy sparse matrix to calculate A dot A.T with less memory

Tags: python, scipy, ctypes, sparse-matrix, intel-mkl

I want to call [mkl.mkl_scsrmultcsr](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/468640) from python. The goal is to calculate a sparse matrix C in [compressed sparse row](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) format. Sparse matrix C is the matrix product between A and transpose of A, where A is also a sparse matrix in csr format. When calculating C = A dot (A.T) with scipy, scipy seems (?) to allocate new memory for holding transpose of A (A.T), and definitely allocates memory for a new C matrix (This means I can't use an existing C matrix). So, I want to try to use the mkl c function directly to decrease memory usage.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158893/does-scipy-support-multithreading-for-sparse-matrix-multiplication-when-using-mk) is an answer that works for another mkl function. In that answer, mkl function was faster by 4 times.

The following version finally works after working on it for 4 days. I want to know if I wasted any memory. Would ctype make any copy of the numpy array? Is that that csr->csc conversion in the test function necessary? The intel c function can calculate (A.T) dot A, or A dot A, but not A dot (A.T).

Thanks again.

```
from ctypes import *
import scipy.sparse as spsp
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
# June 2nd 2016 version.

# Load the share library
mkl = cdll.LoadLibrary("libmkl_rt.so")

def get_csr_handle(A,clear=False):
    if clear == True:
        A.indptr[:] = 0
        A.indices[:] = 0
        A.data[:] = 0

    a_pointer   = A.data.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_float))
     # Array containing non-zero elements of the matrix A.
     # This corresponds to data array of csr_matrix
     # Its length is equal to #non zero elements in A
     # (Can this be longer than actual #non-zero elements?)
    assert A.data.ctypes.data % 16 == 0 # Check alignment

    ja_pointer  = A.indices.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_int))
     # Array of column indices of all non-zero elements of A.
     # This corresponds to the indices array of csr_matrix
    assert A.indices.ctypes.data % 16 == 0 # Check alignment

    ia_pointer  = A.indptr.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_int))
     # Array of length m+1.
     # a[ia[i]:ia[i+1]] is the value of nonzero entries of
     # the ith row of A.
     # ja[ia[i]:ia[i+1]] is the column indices of nonzero
     # entries of the ith row of A
     # This corresponds to the indptr array of csr_matrix
    assert A.indptr.ctypes.data % 16 == 0 # Check alignment

    A_data_size    = A.data.size
    A_indices_size = A.indices.size
    A_indptr_size  = A.indptr.size

    return (a_pointer, ja_pointer, ia_pointer, A)

def csr_dot_csr_t(A_handle, C_handle, nz=None):
    # Calculate (A.T).dot(A) and put result into C
    #
    # This uses one-based indexing
    #
    # Both C.data and A.data must be in np.float32 type.
    #
    # Number of nonzero elements in C must be greater than
    #     or equal to the size of C.data
    #
    # size of C.indptr must be greater than or equal to
    #     1 + (num rows of A).
    #
    # C_data    = np.zeros((nz), dtype=np.single)
    # C_indices = np.zeros((nz), dtype=np.int32)
    # C_indptr  = np.zeros((m+1),dtype=np.int32)

    #assert len(c_pointer._obj) >= 1 + A_shape[0]


    (a_pointer, ja_pointer, ia_pointer, A) = A_handle
    (c_pointer, jc_pointer, ic_pointer, C) = C_handle
    #print "CCC",C
    #assert type(C.data[0]) == np.float32
    #assert type(A.data[0]) == np.float32
    #assert C.indptr.size >= A.shape[0] + 1

    #CC = A.dot(A.T)
    #assert C.data.size >= nz
    #assert C.indices.size >= nz

    trans_pointer   = byref(c_char('T'))
    sort_pointer    = byref(c_int(0))

    (m, n)          = A.shape
    sort_pointer        = byref(c_int(0))
    m_pointer           = byref(c_int(m))     # Number of rows of matrix A
    n_pointer           = byref(c_int(n))     # Number of columns of matrix A
    k_pointer           = byref(c_int(n))     # Number of columns of matrix B
                                              # should be n when trans='T'
                          # Otherwise, I guess should be m
    ###
    b_pointer   = a_pointer
    jb_pointer  = ja_pointer
    ib_pointer  = ia_pointer
    ###
    if nz == None:
        nz = n*n #*n # m*m # Number of nonzero elements expected
             # probably can use lower value for sparse
             # matrices.
    nzmax_pointer   = byref(c_int(nz))
     # length of arrays c and jc. (which are data and
     # indices of csr_matrix). So this is the number of
     # nonzero elements of matrix C
     #
     # This parameter is used only if request=0.
     # The routine stops calculation if the number of
     # elements in the result matrix C exceeds the
     # specified value of nzmax.

    info = c_int(-3)
    info_pointer = byref(info)
    request_pointer_list = [byref(c_int(0)), byref(c_int(1)), byref(c_int(2))]
    return_list = []
    for ii in [0]:
        request_pointer = request_pointer_list[ii]
        ret = mkl.mkl_scsrmultcsr(trans_pointer, request_pointer, sort_pointer,
                    m_pointer, n_pointer, k_pointer,
                    a_pointer, ja_pointer, ia_pointer,
                    b_pointer, jb_pointer, ib_pointer,
                    c_pointer, jc_pointer, ic_pointer,
                    nzmax_pointer, info_pointer)
        info_val = info.value
        return_list += [ (ret,info_val) ]
    return return_list


def show_csr_internal(A, indent=4):
    # Print data, indptr, and indices
    # of a scipy csr_matrix A
    name = ['data', 'indptr', 'indices']
    mat  = [A.data, A.indptr, A.indices]
    for i in range(3):
        str_print = ' '*indent+name[i]+':\n%s'%mat[i]
        str_print = str_print.replace('\n', '\n'+' '*indent*2)
        print(str_print)

def fix_for_scipy(C,A):
    n = A.shape[1]
    print "fix n", n
    nz =  C.indptr[n] - 1 # -1 as this is still one based indexing.
    print "fix nz", nz
    data = C.data[:nz]

    C.indptr[:n+1] -= 1
    indptr = C.indptr[:n+1]
    C.indices[:nz] -= 1
    indices = C.indices[:nz]
    return spsp.csr_matrix( (data, indices, indptr), shape=(n,n))

def test():
    AA= [[1,0,0,1],
         [1,0,1,0],
         [0,0,1,0]]
    AA = np.random.choice([0,1], size=(3,750000), replace=True, p=[0.99,0.01])
    A_original = spsp.csr_matrix(AA)
    #A = spsp.csr_matrix(A_original, dtype=np.float32)
    A = A_original.astype(np.float32).tocsc()
    #A_original = A.todense()
    A = spsp.csr_matrix( (A.data, A.indices, A.indptr) )
    print  "A:"
    show_csr_internal(A)
    print A.todense()
    A.indptr  += 1 # convert to 1-based indexing
    A.indices += 1 # convert to 1-based indexing
    A_ptrs = get_csr_handle(A)

    C = spsp.csr_matrix( np.ones((3,3)), dtype=np.float32)
    #C.data = C.data[:16].view()
    #C.indptr = C.indptr
    C_ptrs = get_csr_handle(C, clear=True)

    print "C:"
    show_csr_internal(C)    
    print "=call mkl function=" 
    return_list= csr_dot_csr_t(A_ptrs, C_ptrs)
    print "(ret, info):", return_list
    print "C after calling mkl:"
    show_csr_internal(C)    

    C_fix = fix_for_scipy(C,A)
    print "C_fix for scipy:"
    show_csr_internal(C_fix)
    print C_fix.todense()

    print "Original C after fixing:"
    show_csr_internal(C)

    print "scipy's (A).dot(A.T)"
    scipy_ans = (A_original).dot(A_original.T)
    #scipy_ans = spsp.csr_matrix(scipy_ans)
    show_csr_internal(scipy_ans)
    print scipy_ans.todense()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

Result:

```
A:
    data:
        [ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]
    indptr:
        [    0     0     0 ..., 22673 22673 22673]
    indices:
        [1 0 2 ..., 2 1 2]
[[ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 ..., 
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]]
C:
    data:
        [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
    indptr:
        [0 0 0 0]
    indices:
        [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
=call mkl function=
(ret, info): [(2, 0)]
C after calling mkl:
    data:
        [ 7576.    77.    83.    77.  7607.   104.    83.   104.  7490.]
    indptr:
        [ 1  4  7 10]
    indices:
        [1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3]
fix n 3
fix nz 9
C_fix for scipy:
    data:
        [ 7576.    77.    83.    77.  7607.   104.    83.   104.  7490.]
    indptr:
        [0 3 6 9]
    indices:
        [0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2]
[[ 7576.    77.    83.]
 [   77.  7607.   104.]
 [   83.   104.  7490.]]
Original C after fixing:
    data:
        [ 7576.    77.    83.    77.  7607.   104.    83.   104.  7490.]
    indptr:
        [0 3 6 9]
    indices:
        [0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2]
scipy's (A.T).dot(A)
    data:
        [  83   77 7576  104   77 7607   83  104 7490]
    indptr:
        [0 3 6 9]
    indices:
        [2 1 0 2 0 1 0 1 2]
[[7576   77   83]
 [  77 7607  104]
 [  83  104 7490]]
```

Things learned:

1. index starts from 1 for matrices A, B, and C.
2. I mixed up c_indptr and c_indices in the original code. Should be ia
   = indptr of scipy csr_matrix. ja = indices of scipy csr_matrix.
3. from the code [here](https://github.com/srkiranraj/spgemm/blob/master/spmm_mkl.cu). Everything is passed to the mkl_?csrmultcsr as a pointer. `mkl_scsrmultcsr(&ta, &r[1], &sort, &m, &m, &m, a, ja, ia,  a, ja, ia, c, jc, ic, &nzmax, &info);`
4. I want a mkl function that can work with zero-based index. The mkl.mkl_scsrmultcsr function can only work with one-based indexing. (Or I can one-based indexing for everything. This means using intel c function instead of scipy/numpy for most linear algebra steps.)

Comment: `data_c` and `c`, created a `A` cleared, has 4 elements.  But the expected results have 7 or 5 nonzero terms.

Comment: The "C = ctype_csr_mat(np.ones((3,3)), clear=True)" line make sure the array of matrix C have enough space to hold the answer. I set nzmax = 100 to make mkl calculate 100 nonzero elements of C.

Comment: Updated code to fix the 1.401298464324817e-45 problem. The result is still not right.

Comment: The indices array from this call of mkl doesn't even match the answer from scipy dot... may be i will try to create a new A and B. Currently B and A both refer to the same csr matrix

Comment: .cu source code that use the intel function: https://github.com/srkiranraj/spgemm/blob/master/spmm_mkl.cu

Comment: The code runs on a westmere intel cpu. I guess i will pick np.single dtype to save memory. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550281/floating-point-vs-integer-calculations-on-modern-hardware

Comment: The intel function can only get (A.T) dot A, but not A dot (A.T) where (A.T) is transpose of A, and dot is matrix product. This means I might need a csr->csc conversion for getting the transpose of A. csr->csc conversion by scipy is slow, but still use far less time than the actual A dot (A.T) matrix multiplication.

Comment: The scipy's conversion from csr->csc also don't use much memory... compared to scipy's dot.

Comment: `A.T` uses views of the `A` attributes (new arrays, same data buffers), just changing the format to `csc`.  So yes that's cheap in memory and time.  But `_mul_sparse_matrix` does a format conversion, `other = self.__class__(other)  # convert to this format`, which consumes memory and time.  The `mkl` `trans` parameter suggests it can work around this issue.  In theory the `sparse` C code could have added that feature, but didn't.

Comment: Actually I mean using A.tocsc(), and then interpret the resulting csc matrix as a csr matrix. It is a way to get A.T in csr form when A is in csr form. That one is not just a view.  This allows calculating ((A.T).T) dot (A.T), which is same as A dot (A.T) with the intel function. The intel function can only get (M.T) dot M or M dot M for matrix M, but not M dot M.T.

Comment: I compiled scipy with mkl. But the June 2nd 2016 version seems faster than Scipy for like 5-10 times on the actual data that I work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the Python code for the scipy sparse product.  Notice that it calls the compiled code in 2 passes.

It looks like the mkl code does the same thing

https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/468640

> If request=1, the routine computes only values of the array ic of length m + 1, the memory for this array must be allocated beforehand. On exit the value ic(m+1) - 1 is the actual number of the elements in the arrays c and jc.
>
> If request=2, the routine has been called previously with the parameter request=1, the output arrays jc and c are allocated in the calling program and they are of the length ic(m+1) - 1 at least.

You first allocated `ic` based on the number of rows of `C` (you know that  from the inputs), and call the mkl code with `request=1`.

For `request=2` you have to allocate `c` and `jc` arrays, based on the size in `ic(m+1) - 1`.  This is not the same as the number of `nnz` in the input arrays.

You are using `request1 = c_int(0)`, which requires that the `c` arrays be the correct size - which you don't know without actually performing the `dot` (or a `request 1`).

==================

```
File:        /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py
Definition:  A._mul_sparse_matrix(self, other)
```

pass 1 allocates `indptr` (note size), and passes the pointers (data doesn't matter at this pass)

```
    indptr = np.empty(major_axis + 1, dtype=idx_dtype)

    fn = getattr(_sparsetools, self.format + '_matmat_pass1')
    fn(M, N,
       np.asarray(self.indptr, dtype=idx_dtype),
       np.asarray(self.indices, dtype=idx_dtype),
       np.asarray(other.indptr, dtype=idx_dtype),
       np.asarray(other.indices, dtype=idx_dtype),
       indptr)

    nnz = indptr[-1]
```

pass 2 allocates `indptr` (different size), and based on `nnz` `indices` and `data`.

```
    indptr = np.asarray(indptr, dtype=idx_dtype)
    indices = np.empty(nnz, dtype=idx_dtype)
    data = np.empty(nnz, dtype=upcast(self.dtype, other.dtype))

    fn = getattr(_sparsetools, self.format + '_matmat_pass2')
    fn(M, N, np.asarray(self.indptr, dtype=idx_dtype),
       np.asarray(self.indices, dtype=idx_dtype),
       self.data,
       np.asarray(other.indptr, dtype=idx_dtype),
       np.asarray(other.indices, dtype=idx_dtype),
       other.data,
       indptr, indices, data)
```

Last make a new array using these arrays.

```
    return self.__class__((data,indices,indptr),shape=(M,N))
```

The `mkl` library should be used in the same way.

===================

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr.h

has c code for `csr_matmat_pass1` and `csr_matmat_pass2`

====================

In case it helps, here's a pure Python implementation of these passes.  A literal translation without any attempt to take advantage of any array operations.

```
def pass1(A, B):
    nrow,ncol=A.shape
    Aptr=A.indptr
    Bptr=B.indptr
    Cp=np.zeros(nrow+1,int)
    mask=np.zeros(ncol,int)-1
    nnz=0
    for i in range(nrow):
        row_nnz=0
        for jj in range(Aptr[i],Aptr[i+1]):
            j=A.indices[jj]
            for kk in range(Bptr[j],Bptr[j+1]):
                k=B.indices[kk]
                if mask[k]!=i:
                    mask[k]=i
                    row_nnz += 1
        nnz += row_nnz
        Cp[i+1]=nnz
    return Cp
    
def pass2(A,B,Cnnz):
    nrow,ncol=A.shape
    Ap,Aj,Ax=A.indptr,A.indices,A.data
    Bp,Bj,Bx=B.indptr,B.indices,B.data

    next = np.zeros(ncol,int)-1
    sums = np.zeros(ncol,A.dtype)
    
    Cp=np.zeros(nrow+1,int)
    Cj=np.zeros(Cnnz,int)
    Cx=np.zeros(Cnnz,A.dtype)
    nnz = 0
    for i in range(nrow):
        head = -2
        length = 0
        for jj in range(Ap[i], Ap[i+1]):
            j, v = Aj[jj], Ax[jj]
            for kk in range(Bp[j], Bp[j+1]):
                k = Bj[kk]
                sums[k] += v*Bx[kk]
                if (next[k]==-1):
                    next[k], head=head, k
                    length += 1
        print(i,sums, next)
        for _ in range(length):
            if sums[head] !=0:
                Cj[nnz], Cx[nnz] = head, sums[head]
                nnz += 1
            temp = head
            head = next[head]
            next[temp], sums[temp] = -1, 0
        Cp[i+1] = nnz            
    return Cp, Cj, Cx                  
    
def pass0(A,B):
    Cp = pass1(A,B)
    nnz = Cp[-1]
    Cp,Cj,Cx=pass2(A,B,nnz)
    N,M=A.shape[0], B.shape[1]
    C=sparse.csr_matrix((Cx, Cj, Cp), shape=(N,M))
    return C
```

Both `A` and `B` have to be `csr`.  It using a transpose it needs conversion, e.g. `B = A.T.tocsr()`.

Comment: thank you for pointing to the passes require to get the answer. That doesn't solve the whole puzzle though. I modified the code to test several passes. The ic (indices) of matrix C did get modified in pass 0. But pass 1 and pass 2 didn't change c or jc.

Comment: But then request=0 (the 0th pass) is supposed to calculate everything. "If request=0, the routine performs multiplication, the memory for the output arrays ic, jc, c must be allocated beforehand."

Comment: may be i didn't convert the input csr matrix to the correct data type? So mkl only get zero from the data array of the input csr matrix? Yup. The line in the resul "[1.401298464324817e-45, 0.0, 1.401298464324817e-45, 0.0, 1.401298464324817e-45]" is wrong for matrix A and B.

Comment: .astype(dtype) seems the problem. can't change data type that way.

Comment: That problem get fixed. But it still doesn't give the correct answer.

Comment: I added a literal translation of the sparse C code.

Comment: Thank you very much for the translation. When I use scipy to do A dot (A.T), scipy uses lots of memory. May be it is because that scipy need to transpose A and put the transpose into a new chunk of memory? I will look at the code to see if that is the case. Memory usage is the main reason that I try to directly call the intel function.