# Sparse Matrix-Matrix Multiplication Using SciPy and Numba

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, numba

I am trying to speedup some sparse matrix-matrix multiplications in Python using Numba and it's JIT compiler. Unfortunately it doesn't support the SciPy library as I need it.

My solution is to translate the functions `csr_matmat_pass1()` and `csr_matmat_pass2()` from [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr.h#L476) into Python code. My code seems to work for matrices smaller than ~80x80 and delivers correct results. Here's my solution:

```
import scipy.sparse as sparse
import numpy as np

def csr_matmat_pass1(n_row, n_col, Ap, Aj, Bp, Bj):   
   mask = np.ones(n_col, dtype="int") * -1
   Cp = np.zeros(n_row+1, dtype="int")

   nnz = 0
   for i in range(n_row):
       row_nnz = 0

       for jj in range(Ap[i],Ap[i+1]):
           j = Aj[jj]
           for kk in range(Bp[j],Bp[j+1]):
               k = Bj[kk]

               if(mask[k] != i):
                   mask[k] = i
                   row_nnz += 1


       next_nnz = nnz + row_nnz;

       nnz = next_nnz;
       Cp[i+1] = nnz;
   return Cp            

def csr_matmat_pass2(n_row, n_col, Ap, Aj, Ax, Bp, Bj, Bx, Cp):
   nextV = np.ones(n_col, dtype="int") * -1
   sums = np.zeros(n_col)

   nnz = 0

   Cp[0] = 0
   #preallocate space
   sizeC = max(len(Ax),len(Bx)) 
   Cj = np.zeros(sizeC, dtype="int")
   Cx = np.zeros(sizeC)

   for i in range(n_row):
       head   = -2
       length =  0

       jj_start = Ap[i]
       jj_end   = Ap[i+1]
       for jj in range(jj_start,jj_end):   
           j = Aj[jj]
           v = Ax[jj]

           kk_start = Bp[j]
           kk_end   = Bp[j+1]
           for kk in range(kk_start,kk_end):
               k = Bj[kk]

               sums[k] += v*Bx[kk]

               if(nextV[k] == -1):
                   nextV[k] = head
                   head  = k
                   length += 1

       for jj in range(length):

           if(sums[head] != 0.0):
               Cj[nnz] = head
               Cx[nnz] = sums[head]
               nnz += 1


           temp = head     
           head = nextV[head]

           nextV[temp] = -1
           sums[temp] =  0


       Cp[i+1] = nnz
   return Cp, Cj, Cx

#calculate random sparse matrices A,B
mSize = 50
A = sparse.random(mSize, mSize, 0.01).tocsr()
B = sparse.random(mSize, mSize, 0.01).tocsr() 

#calculate sparse C  
Cp = csr_matmat_pass1(np.shape(A)[0], np.shape(B)[1], A.indptr, A.indices, B.indptr, B.indices)
Cp, Cj, Cx = csr_matmat_pass2(np.shape(A)[0], np.shape(B)[1], A.indptr, A.indices, A.data, B.indptr, B.indices, B.data, Cp)
#generate numpy sparse matrix from Cx, Cj, Cp    
C = sparse.csr_matrix((Cx,Cj,Cp),shape=(nRow,nCol))


diffC = A.dot(B) - C

#validate function -> check if any nonzero element is present. If so -> calc is wrong
if np.any(diffC.todense()): UserWarning('Calculations are wrong')
```

When increasing the size of the matrices (lets say `mSize=100`) I get the following error:

```
line 168, in csr_matmat_pass2 Cj[nnz] = head

IndexError: index 72 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 72
```

I assume the error is in my python translation rather than in the C++ code (since it is from the scipy library). Also `Cp` has greater entries than the size of the matrices `A`, `B`. For that reason there must be an error in the translation of `csr_matmat_pass1()`. Unfortunately I cannot find any syntax errors and don't know why `nnz` gets bigger than it should.

Comment: I made this kind of translation in http://stackoverflow.com/a/37540149/901925 (last May).  There the question was about replacing the `scipy` code with calls to the `mkl` library.  What do you hope to accomplish by replacing `c` code with `numba` compiled code?

Comment: Where does that `sizeC` in `pass2` come from?  In my translation this comes from the value of the last element of `Cp` as calculated in `pass1`.  Your code doesn't seem to make any use of the results of `pass1`.  Are you new to `c` as well as `python`?

Comment: In the `csr.h` file, the `c` does not allocate `Cx`, `Cj`.  That's done in the `compressed.py` code.  And it uses `nnz`, which is `nnz = indptr[-1]`.

Comment: That resolved my problem. Thank you!

1. I try to get a speed increase using the JIT compiler. 

2. That was the error. Indeed my c skills are quite rusty and the problem was the wrong allocation with sizeC. 

3. After pass1 I had to replace the allocation of Cj, Cx and Cp as follows

       `Cp = csr_matmat_pass1(n_row, n_col, Ap, Aj, Bp, Bj, mask, Cp)`
    
    `#allocate arrays for pass2
    Cj=np.zeros(Cp[-1], int)
    Cx=np.zeros(Cp[-1], A.dtype)
    Cp=np.zeros(n_row+1,int)`